# Set a UserControl Property to Not Show Up in VS Properties Window

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, properties, attributes

I have a UserControl in my Asp.net project that has a public property. I do not want this property to show up in the Visual Studio Property Window when a user highlights an instance of the UserControl in the IDE. What attribute (or other method) should I use to prevent it from showing up?

```
class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
  // Attribute to prevent property from showing in VS Property Window?
  public bool SampleProperty { get; set; }

  // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following attribute ...

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[Browsable(false)]
public bool SampleProperty { get; set; }
```

In VB.net, this [will be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440/set-a-usercontrol-property-to-not-show-up-in-vs-properties-window#71481):

```
<System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Tons of attributes](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PropertyGridInCSharp11302005004139AM/PropertyGridInCSharp.aspx) out there to control how the PropertyGrid works.

```
[Browsable(false)]
public bool HiddenProperty {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `System.ComponentModel.Browsable` attribute to

```
> ' VB
> 
>     <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)>
```

or

```
// C#
    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
```